# Giving users custom url to see visual reports using web.py

Tags: jquery, html, python-2.7, matplotlib, web.py

I have a lightweight page designed using web.py - amonst others it takes inputs from users, has a python script that gets executed in the framework - and generates some images using matplotlib. 
I then dump all the images to s3 - and send an email to user (with the location of reports) who initiated that session/form fill up - what I want to do is also give user a **bitly like custom url** that gets appended as follows, 
http://0.0.0.0:8080/static/my_unique_custom_url_timestamped.png

When I look at web.py framework, it looks like I need to [predefine all urls](http://webpy.org/cookbook/url_handling)

1. Assuming I have 5 .png files, that I convert to a nicely formatted html page - can I share a custom url with users , where they can visually look at the charts/report - How do I communicate this back to web.py ?
2. Is it necessary to store all the images to "static" directory, or can I just create the html - which references all these image, in a tmp directory, - and share this html.

I also used jquery/javascript to build part of the form - and I am ok to extend this using js, though I would prefer a pythonic way.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, web.py's "predefined" URLs include regular expression patterns.

You have two general approaches:

1. Use single URL, but send your unique timestamped png as part of query string. Your URL might be something like `/images?name=my_unique_custom_url_timestamped.png`. The web.py URL would simply be predefined as `'/images'`, and within that URL's handler class, call `web.input().name` to get the requested file name.

   ```
   class MyImageHander(object):
       def GET(self):
            png_name = web.input().name
            ...
   ```
2. Or, to use a URL like `/images/my_unique_custom_url_timestamped.png`, define the web.py URL using the regular expression `'/images/([^/]+.png)'`. Note how the regex will capture everything after the leading `/images/`. web.py will pass this captured value to the GET method of the class handling the URL.

   ```
   class MyImageHandler(object):
        def GET(self, png_name):
            ...
   ```

Either way, web.py URL is predefined.

One caution, if you're taking user input and are going to grab something off of your filesystem, be sure the do it safely: You don't want the user to be able to say `/images?name=../../../etc/password` and you blindly handing him the keys to your castle.